# Repeat an if statement if it goes to 'else'

Tags: ruby

It is possible to let repeat an if statement if it goes to 'else'?

This is a part of a code:

```
puts "While you are walking you find a small jar containing honey. Do
you take it? yes/not"

choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

if choice.include?("yes")
  honey = true
  puts " "
  puts "You put the small honey jar in your bag and then keep walking."

elsif choice.include?("not")
  puts "Ok! maybe you are right. Better leave it!"
  puts "You keep going"
  honey = false

else
  " "
  puts "Answer yes or not."

end
```

So I would like that if the user do not type yes or not the if statement run again, maybe asking again the question or just giving the 'else' message and giving again the possibility to write the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're programming a text-based game, you might want to define a method:

```
def ask(question, messages, choices = %w(yes no), values = [true, false])
  puts question
  puts choices.join(' / ')
  choice = $stdin.gets.chomp
  message, choice, value = messages.zip(choices, values).find do |_m, c, _v|
    choice.include?(c)
  end
  if message
    puts message
    value
  else
    puts "Please answer with #{choices.join(' or ')}"
    puts
  end
end

question = 'While you are walking you find a small jar containing honey. Do you take it?'
messages = ['You put the small honey jar in your bag and then keep walking.',
            "Ok! maybe you are right. Better leave it!\nYou keep going"]

honey = ask(question, messages) while honey.nil?
puts honey
```

This will loop until a valid answer is provided.

As an example:

```
While you are walking you find a small jar containing honey. Do you take it?
yes / no
who cares?
Please answer with yes or no

While you are walking you find a small jar containing honey. Do you take it?
yes / no
okay
Please answer with yes or no

While you are walking you find a small jar containing honey. Do you take it?
yes / no
yes
You put the small honey jar in your bag and then keep walking.
true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap that in a loop:

```
loop do
  puts "While you are walking you find a small jar containing honey. Do
    you take it? yes/not"

  choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

  if choice.include?("yes")
    honey = true
    puts " "
    puts "You put the small honey jar in your bag and then keep walking."
    break
  elsif ...
    ...
    break
  else
    puts "Answer yes or not."
  end

end
```

If you don't explicitly break from the loop (which you do when user gives expected input), then it will automatically rerun.

Comment: Thank for the tips. However, In this case, I decided to use 'while' instead of 'loop do' because in the loop I needed to modify a local variable and use it after the loop do.  Using 'while' this is possible with 'loop do' this is not. The local variable wouldn't be modified.

Comment: @MarcoVanali: it's still a loop :) You can also look at Eric's answer. Very useful.